# Split string variable of log input and output pieces in text file (PERL)

Tags: string, perl, logging, output, editor

I have the following entry in my logfile.

```
[2016-04-17 10:12:27:682011 GMT] tcp 115.239.248.245:1751 -> 192.168.0.17:8080 52976f9f34d5c286ecf70cac6fba4506 04159c6111bca4f83d7d606a617acc5d6a58328d3a631adf3795f66a5d6265f4d1ec99977a5ae8cb2f3133c9503e5086a5f2ac92be196bb0c9a9f653f9669495 (312 bytes)
```

I want to write a script to split this one line string into pieces in order to write some of these pieces in a .csv file for machine learning. Till now I got this script to find a certain pattern and if found write what it was given to find, hardcoded search. This is not what I want. This is the script I have right now.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

$path1 = "/home/tsec/testwatch/attackerresult.log";
$attacker = ">>/home/tsec/testwatch/attacker.csv";
#$path2 =
#$path3 =
#$path4 =

#function definition #Pattern for attackerlog only
sub extractor(){
open(LOG, $path1) or die "Cant't open '$path1': $!";
open(FILE, $attacker) or die "Can't open '$attacker': $!";

$target = "tcp";

while(<LOG>){

        if(/$target/){
        print FILE $target . "\n";

        }
}
}
close(LOG);
close(FILE);
```

I want the output in the CSV file to be something like this:

I can do the csv titles manually

(Titles)Protocol, Source IP Address, Source Port, File Size

(String result from script)tcp, 127.0.0.1, 8080, 312

The above is just an example.

Any idea?

Comment: The required output appears to be unrelated to the input that you show

Comment: [x-posted at PerlMonks](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1160718)

Answer (score 0):

If all lines will always have the same number of fields, this will work.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $wfh, '>', 'out.csv' or die $!;

my $cols = "Protocol, Source IP Address, Source Port, File Size\n";
print $wfh $cols;

while (<DATA>){
    if (/
          (?:.*?\s){3}  # get rid of the time
          (.*?)         # capture the proto ($1)
          \s+           # skip the next whitespace    
          (.*?):(\d+)   # separate IP and port, capture both ($2, $3)
          .*?\(         # skip everything until an opening parens
          (\d+)         # capture bytes ($4)
        /x
       ){
        print $wfh "$1, $2, $3, $4\n";
    }
}


__DATA__
2016-04-17 10:12:27:682011 GMT tcp 115.239.248.245:1751 -> 192.168.0.17:8080 52976f9f34d5c286ecf70cac6fba4506 04159c6111bca4f83d7d606a617acc5d6a58328d3a631adf3795f66a5d6265f4d1ec99977a5ae8cb2f3133c9503e5086a5f2ac92be196bb0c9a9f653f9669495 (312 bytes)
```

Output file:

```
Protocol, Source IP Address, Source Port, File Size
tcp, 115.239.248.245, 1751, 312
```